# Error injecting: com.google.appengine.devappserver.DevAppServerRunner?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven

I am not able to deploy my App Engine project locally. `mvn clean install` results in `Build Success` but when I execute `mvn appengine:devserver`, I get the following error:

```
[WARNING] Error injecting: com.google.appengine.devappserver.DevAppServerRunner
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.google.appengine.devappserver.DevAppServerRunner not present
at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:115)
at org.eclipse.sisu.space.NamedClass.load(NamedClass.java:46)
at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:55)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:133)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:109)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:997)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1047)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:993)
at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:260)
at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:252)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:462)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:119)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/appengine/devappserver/DevAppServerRunner : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:389)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:242)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:107)
... 41 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.471 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-11-21T16:22:29+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-    plugin:1.9.17:devserver (default-cli) on project shopmate-api: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.17:devserver failed: Unable to load the mojo 'devserver' in the plugin 'com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.17' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: com/google/appengine/devappserver/DevAppServerRunner : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.17
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/Users/ramswaroop/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-maven-plugin/1.9.17/appengine-maven-plugin-1.9.17.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/Users/ramswaroop/.m2/repository/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/1.0/cdi-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/Users/ramswaroop/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/jsr250-api/1.0/jsr250-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/Users/ramswaroop/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/Users/ramswaroop/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/3.1.0/sisu-guice-3.1.0-no_aop.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/Users/ramswaroop/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/Users/ramswaroop/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/sisu/org.eclipse.sisu.inject/0.0.0.M5/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.0.0.M5.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/Users/ramswaroop/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.19/plexus-interpolation-1.19.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/Users/ramswaroop/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.17/plexus-utils-3.0.17.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/Users/ramswaroop/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/Users/ramswaroop/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/Users/ramswaroop/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/Users/ramswaroop/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/0.9.1.v20140329/aether-util-0.9.1.v20140329.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/Users/ramswaroop/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/Users/ramswaroop/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-tools-sdk/1.9.17/appengine-tools-sdk-1.9.17.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/Users/ramswaroop/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-local-endpoints/1.9.17/appengine-local-endpoints-1.9.17.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/Users/ramswaroop/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-endpoints/1.9.17/appengine-endpoints-1.9.17.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/Users/ramswaroop/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk/1.9.17/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.17.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/Users/ramswaroop/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/Users/ramswaroop/.m2/repository/eu/infomas/annotation-detector/3.0.4/annotation-detector-3.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/Users/ramswaroop/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-nop/1.7.7/slf4j-nop-1.7.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/Users/ramswaroop/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.7/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/Users/ramswaroop/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-invoker/2.1.1/maven-invoker-2.1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

NOTE: I am using Maven 3.2.3 and appengine-maven-plugin 1.9.17.

Comment: what version of the GAE SDK are you running on?